# Media query issues when resizing to mobile and then back to Desktop

Tags: mobile, media-queries, navigationbar

I have a site which uses a different menu for mobile devices than on the Desktop version using media queries. If I resize a desktop browser window to a mobile width and click the mobile navigation dropdown button and then resize the window back to desktop size, the mobile menu remains visible instead of changing back to display:none. Unfortunately this site is still in staging so I cannot show you a live example, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of getting that DIV to become hidden again once the window is resized back to full screen.

Also, I realize that the chances of this scenario playing out in the real world are slim, but the client would like for it to be addressed anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be happy to attempt to help, however you never gave any feedback on the last question I answered from you.  So i'm not very motivated to spend time answering a question for naught.

Comment: I really do appreciate your support Trevor. The slider auto-pause issue is on the backburner currently as we address other more pertinent issues but I will definitely get back to you on that.

Comment: Glad you got your issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was javascript that was showing the DIV in the first place, not a media query, so I just added display:none to the div for the Desktop media query and the issue has gone away. Thanks!